# Sending cancel parameter C#

Tags: c#

Okay, this is my whole code. Now... `Detail_BeforePrint()` will be called first, and `xrPictureBox8_BeforePrint` second.
Now I want to call `Detail_BeforePrint` `e.Cancel = true;` inside the `else` in `xrPictureBox8_BeforePrint` event.

```
 private void Detail_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
        {
    //here should e.Cancel = true be if it came from xrPictureBox_BeforePrint()
        }

    private void xrPictureBox8_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (xrPictureBox8.ImageUrl.Length > 0) { }
            else
            {
           Detail_BeforePrint(null,[call Cancel parameter]);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: this question is far too vague - I've read it 3 times now and I still am not sure what you need help with. what are you trying to accomplish, and what exactly is your question. also, provide a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help?

```
private void Detail_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    DoDetail_BeforePrint(e, false);
}

private void DoDetail_BeforePrint(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e, bool cancel)
{
    if (cancel) e.Cancel = true;
    //other things
}

private void xrPictureBox8_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (xrPictureBox8.ImageUrl.Length > 0) { }
        else
        {
            DoDetail_BeforePrint(e, true);
            //or just call e.Cancel = true here?
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```